# how to re-execute code inside a loop

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net application that uses a loop like the below:

```
While Not EOF(0)
    If value = value2 Then
        ..execute code here
    Else
        'display error
        MsgBox("Not Found")
    End If
End While
```

This is basically looping though a file and matching data in a database. If there is no match found it will MsgBox an error, so when this displays i want to be able to add the necessary row into my database and then close the message box and re run the code but not the whole loop and just the one that has failed

Comment: So far you haven't told us your problem, other than that you don't have the code to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make something like

```
While Not EOF(0)
    If value = value2 Then
        ..execute code here
    Else
       'display error
       new_value = InputBox("Insert new value", "Not Found", value)
       'here your code, where you can try to update the table row with new value
   End If
End While
```

InputBox will stop for the moment your loop and continue after submit.